# Rails 4.2.4 - dynamic menus in simple form with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, menu, associations

I want to populate one selection field based on choice from other selected field. It's about categories / subcategories, when user is trying to submit new product. User picks main category in field 1, after picked main category he gets option to pick from field 2 children subcategories of picked main category from field 1. It's based on associations so it makes it harder for me.

Product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user      
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations    
end
```

Category model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category"
  has_many :children, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, through: :categorizations
end
```

Categorization model:

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @product, :html => { multipart: true } do |f| %>      
  <%= f.association :categories, collection: Category.where(parent_id: nil), prompt: 'Choose category' %>
  <%= f.association :categories, collection: Category.where.not(parent_id: nil), prompt: 'Choose subcategory' %>      
  <%= f.button :submit, "Submit product" %>
<% end %>
```

UPDATE:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def update_categories
    @categories = Category.where("parent_id = ?", params[:category_id])
    respond_to do |format|
     format.js
    end
  end
end
```

some routes:

```
get 'products/update_categories', as: 'update_categories'
```

Comment: You need to fetch the data for sub-category and populate the second select using the first selected value. There are no inbuilt methods to achieve this.

Comment: Can you give me more tips? I don't know in what direction should I go. After that I will post my code.

Comment: On the first select, you need to implement a function on "select" event in JavaScript. When the user selects a category your function will run. In that function you can fetch subcategories of that category using a new GET route in your application and populate the second select. I hope you understand this :)

Comment: I added some controller logic and route, but how to do js? Sorry but I am really a noob.

Comment: You might be using jQuery in your application. You can learn how to handle HTML element events on jQuery using jQuery's `on` function. There is a `change` and `select` event fired when a user selects a value from drop-down. You need to run a function on that event.